# java program runs in eclipse but not in the terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, netbeans, terminal

I can run following code in Eclipse without any problem:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Rect extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.drawRect(10, 60, 40, 30);
        g.fillRect(10, 60, 40, 30);
    }
}
```

but when I try to run the exact same code from terminal by typing using 'javac' & 'java' commands I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

How can I run this exact programs in terminal flawlessly & what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Well, running an Applet from the command line with `java` is going to be ... rather difficult.

Comment: You need to have a main class with a static main function

Comment: I think you're confusing Applets with plain java programs, which require `public static void main` method.

Comment: Use **appletviewer** instead of **java**.

Answer (score 1):

Applets aren't ran usually from a main method. You can create your applet from there if you choose to do so, apart from that you would most likely have to create a html file to execute the code from a command terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Create main function and call the paint(); or try html file approach.